# HSQLDB 2.3 and issues with parameter binding

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, hsqldb

I have a production Oracle database and I am using HSQLDB 2.3 as a integration test DB to verify some DAO methods. I notice HSQL does not deal very well with dates and parameter binding from Java's PreparedStatement. For example, the query below works as expected, assuming column2 is a date type:

```
select
    column1,
    column2
from
    table
where
    trunc(column2) = trunc(sysdate + 14)
    and column3 = ?
```

But this another query simply does not work when I set an Int, `preparedStatement.setInt(1, 14)`, on the first parameter (?). Needless to say it works perfectly in Oracle.

```
select
    column1,
    column2
from
    table
where
    trunc(column2) = trunc(sysdate + ?)
    and column3 = ?
```

Curiously, if you try something like `select (sysdate + 14) future from any_single_row_table` it works as expected, but it shows the current date if you try `select (sysdate + ?) future from any_single_row_table`

Why does it behave like this? Is it a bug in HSQL prepared statement implementation? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Another good example why it's a bad idea to use a different DBMS for testing than you use in production.

Comment: In my perfect world Oracle and all big players would have extremely light "in-memory" databases for test purposes, so we would not have this sort of mismatch. But unfortunately this is not true in the cruel real world and we have to fall on these suboptimal solutions to keep going and deliver quality products.

Comment: I don't see the need for a light in-memory database for testing. Just setup a server where Oracle runs and let your unit test connect to that. It can even run on your CI server - if you don't put heavy load on it Oracle actually doesn't require that many resources. Your current problem is only the tip of the iceberg

Comment: Your solution is cool if you have a very small team working on the same components, otherwise it is a nightmare, because you can never know for sure what is the DB state or neither if the DDL was changed. And installing Oracle XE in every developer workstation is an overkill. Actually this is an endless discussion.

Comment: I wasn't talking about one install on ever developer's computer. I was talking about one *dedicated* server that is used by all unit test. And of course you need something like Liquibase that integrates with your build system to keep the DB model up-to-date automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You are using simple date arithmetic which is specific to Oracle and to some extent supported by HSQLDB. You can try an explicit INTERVAL value which is Standard SQL. You should also use the very latest version of HSQLDB (currently 2.3.3 release candidate) as syntax compatibility has evolved in each version:

```
select
    column1,
    column2
from
    table
where
    trunc(column2) = trunc(sysdate + cast(? as interval day))
    and column3 = ?
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that is the case because, as said above, the date operation works pretty well. If I replace the parameter by the int literal, it runs like a charm. It seems something related to the PreparedStatement implementation, but unfortunately I didn't have the chance to confirm that yet. But I will follow your second advice and will give 2.3.3 a chance (currently I am using 2.3.2).

Comment: There is a major difference between a parameter (it has no type) and a literal (it has a type). Parameter type determination may be doing it wrong and can be forced with CAST.